# which word preposition is correct in or on

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, phrase-choice

Which one is correct?

> "I'll head on that direction"

or

> "I'll head in that direction"

when somebody asks me to be in certain place soon

Answer (score 1):

"I'll head in that direction" is correct.

Answer (score 0):

"I'll head in that direction" would be the correct choice between the two you asked.

However, you could also say "I'll head on over there" or "I'll head on over to that direction" or even "I'll head on over in that direction" and it'll essentially mean the same thing.